# Is the author of the Shu"t HaRidvaz the same one as the one known to be the rebbe of the Ariza"l?

Tags: history, mysticism-kabbalah, arizal

I've heard that the Ariza"l was a talmid of the Ridvaz. I am wondering if it is the same person who authored the Shu"t HaRidvaz as I find that interesting since he seems to be someone that devoted his life to niglah rather than to nistar?

Comment: Do you mean [Radvaz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_ben_Solomon_ibn_Abi_Zimra) rather than [Ridvaz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_Dovid_Wilovsky)?

Comment: Niglah and nistar are not at all mutually exclusive pursuits. On the contrary, knowledge of nigleh is a prerequisite for nistar, and there have been many scholars known for both - Ramban and Sfas Emes come to mind, among many others.

Answer (score 8):

Indeed, this is the same person. The entry for "David ben Solomon ibn Zimra (Radbaz)" in *[The Responsa Literature](https://books.google.com/books?id=iUgwAAAAYAAJ&q=inauthor:%22Solomon%20Bennett%20Freehof%22&dq=inauthor:%22Solomon%20Bennett%20Freehof%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiM2rWCme7iAhWD2FkKHfp7BlsQ6AEIPjAE)* states:

> He conducted a large *yeshiba* and many famous scholars were his pupils. The great talmudic author, Bezalel Ashkenazi, was one of them; and Isaac Luria, the world-famous kabbalist, was another.

As for your impression about devoting his life to *niglah* rather than *nistar*, the following is also stated there:

> He wrote many works, commentaries on Maimonides, rules of talmudic interpretation, kabbalistic commentaries; but, above all, he was a great respondent. Questions came to him from all over the world.

Thus, he did engage in *nistar* as well, but he couldn't ignore all the questions he was receiving to focus solely on *nistar*.

Similarly, in Chapter Seven of *[Theology in the Responsa](https://books.google.com/books?id=vvLfAAAACAAJ&dq=theology%20in%20the%20responsa&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiku53QmO7iAhWFv1kKHVh1DSYQ6AEIKjAA)* we find the following statements about Radbaz:

> Next to Adret, the most prolific writer of Responsa in the history of that literature is  R. David Ibn Abi Zimra (1479-1573), known, after the initial letters of his name, as *Radbaz*.

> In addition to his profound mastery of the Talmud and the legal literature, he was a renowned Kabbalist.

However, this personage should not be confused with R. Yaakov Dovid Wilovsky, who is referred to by the acronym R**i**dvaz or R**i**dbaz. Indeed, this is explicitly cautioned on the latter's [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_Dovid_Wilovsky):

> *Not to be confused with Rabbi [David ben Solomon ibn Abi Zimra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_ben_Solomon_ibn_Abi_Zimra), known as the Radvaz.*